# How to close the menu one by one when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with three levels of nesting. I open each one in turn with the following code:

```js
$(".menu-item-has-children").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
  <a>About</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a>Subitem1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a>Subitem2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Subitem3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

The first level of nesting opens well. And when I try to open the next level, the previous one closes. And when I open it again, the next one is open. How can I fix this and make it possible to open and close the menu one by one?
[image: Menu structure]

Comment: Edit the code snippet to include enough HTML to have a reproducible example.

Comment: Edited. Now if you click on "Subitem2", then all the menus and the top level will close, but the lower level menu will open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation();` instead of `event.preventDefault();`.

`stopPropagation` stops the current event from spreading further during the capturing and bubbling stages.

Example:

```js
$(".menu-item-has-children").click(function(event) {
  //event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
  <a>About</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a>Subitem1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a>Subitem2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Subitem3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```